# USB interface recording, adjust phone monitor volume in BOSS ME 25

Tags: guitar-effects, homerecording, audacity

I recently tried to record my guitar playing using a USB interface in ME 25.
I recorded it using Audacity. I used a headphone monitor plugged in the phone jack to hear my playing.

I struggle with the guitar volume, when I hear the guitar sound from the headphone it's already loud enough. But when I play back the recording I get a very low volume.
I tried increasing the volume using the volume knob and the pedal, but that translated to increase in volume in both the recording software and in my headphone. I can't stand more volume in my headphone, it's already loud, I only want to increase the volume in Audacity.

I got some reference from the owner manual:

> Use your computer’s software to adjust the level of the signal input
> via USB (it cannot be adjusted on the ME-25 itself). To adjust the
> volume of a guitar, use the expression pedal or adjust other volume
> related parameters.
>
> To monitor the sound being input, first lower
> the volume all the way using your computer’s software. Then, gradually
> raise the level until you’ve obtained the amount of volume you want.

From the manual, it suggests that the signal level can't be adjusted in ME 25, but I can adjust it using the volume knob / the pedal; that's weird. I know to resolve this I can just increase the volume after recording, but does that mean I get more 'dirty' signal?

Did anybody try recording with this setup? ME 25 + audacity + headphone monitor?
How did you resolve this?

Increase the volume after recording? Withstand the painful volume in your headphone monitor? Or another way?

Answer (score 1):

what I do is lower the volume on ME, then raising the computer volume and the software volume (audacity in your case) or put up the gain on every recording you make.

If you find a better way it would be glad to know!

Comment: Did you experience more noise if you do this that way?

Comment: Quite weird, but this is what they suggest in the manual. It seems that the unit doesn't have analog volume control.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Manual screenshot]

> Increase the volume after recording?

This is what Boss suggests in the manual. It seems that there is indeed no dedicated analog volume control in the unit.

There is also no volume control for the AUX input.

> Withstand the painful volume in your headphone monitor?

Definitely not!  I really hope that this is not what you were doing last 4 years! Protect your hearing.

What I would suggest are headphones with volume control, that allow to reduce the volume, or an extension headphone cable with such feature.